# Starting a Command Prompt from the Desktop in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I found how to add opening a command prompt to the right-click menu here -

- [How to start a command prompt in a folder in Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320148/how-to-start-a-command-prompt-in-a-folder-in-windows-server-2003-windo)

This works in File Explorer on Folder and whitespace selection, but only on folders for the Desktop.

When I right-click on the desktop and select this I see the following -

[image]

**Task:**

- Location specified command prompt start

**Method:**

- Context menu selection through right-click of target location

**Right-Click Locations:**

```
A. Folder in File Explorer
B. File Area in File Explorer
C. Folder on Desktop
D. File Area on Desktop (e.g. right-clicking empty space)
```

**Status:**

- #D is not working for my computer. A/B/C work as expected

What is causing this error?

Comment: Undo your registry edit, then see this article, it is built into W10 except it offers powershell instead of cmd.....https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-from-right-click-menu

Answer (score 4):

Those instructions are for much older versions of Windows.

On Windows 10, two new keyboard shortcuts exist:

**Command Prompt:**

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

**Administrator Command Prompt:**

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>

**Note:**

<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> work for the English version of Windows 10. For other languages these might be different.

After you press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> you will see one letter underlined in each menu item (usually the first or second letter) which is the keyboard shortcut for that item.

[image]

**Note:**

These shortcuts can be configured to open either PowerShell or Command Prompt.

The default option is PowerShell but this can easily be toggled to Command Prompt in Taskbar Settings:

[image]

Comment: this solution is language specific! c and a might be different in a non English win10 os, I added a bit of explanation

Comment: Thanks Albin! I decided not to mention other languages just in the interest of brevity but perhaps it is worth mentioning it after all. 

Comment: Hi Mr. Ethernet, those shortcuts rock, thank you! This does not not address the original question though, I have updated the question with more details

Comment: Does the issue only happen in your Windows user account or with all accounts?